# Example on basis change

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am reading the book Mathematics for Machine Learning by Marc Peter Deisenroth, A. Aldo Faisal, and Cheng Soon Ong.

I have a problem understanding an example in this book:

**Example 2.23 (Basis change)** (page 53-54)

Consider a transformation matrix
$\bf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$
with respect to the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If we define a new basis $B=(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix})$ we obtain a diagonal transformation matrix $\tilde{\mathbf{A}}=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ with respect to $B$, which is easier to work than with $\mathbf{A}$.

May I ask why we could obtain $\tilde{\mathbf{A}}$ as above?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you don't understand the calculation try to represent the standard basis using $B$, if you are asking how come we can find a diagonal matrix the question is that this matrix has two eigenvalues, 3 and 1. That is, there is a vector such that $Av=3v$ and another such that $Au=u$. Eigenvalues and eigenvectors are a central topic of linear algebra and your book surely refers to this subject in later chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$. We have
\begin{align}
    \mathbf Av_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\3\end{bmatrix} = \color{red}{3}v_1+\color{red}{0}v_2, \\
    \mathbf Av_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \color{blue}{0}v_1+\color{blue}{1}v_2.
\end{align}
Hence, with respect to the basis $B=(v_1,v_2)$ in both domain and codomain of the map $x\mapsto\mathbf Ax$, we obtain the matrix
$$
\mathbf{\tilde A} = \begin{bmatrix} \color{red}3 & \color{blue}0 \\ \color{red}0 & \color{blue}1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! At this point of the book they just showed the concept of transformation matrix but not fully the basis change. I tried to use just the knowledge of transformation to solve this.